# Show that $u\in Im(S)^\perp$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a hilbert space let $u,v \in H^2$ and  a linear operator $S:H\to H$ s.t $(Sx,x)\geq 0$
let $u\in ker(S)$  verify that $\forall t\in \mathbb R$,$(tSv|u-tv)\geq 0$
Then show that $u\in Im(S)^\perp$

my attempt:
I'm not sure about the first question.
But we have that  $u\in ker(S)$ then $Su=0$ and  since $(tSv|u-tv)\geq 0$ $\implies$ $t(Sv|u)-t^2(Sv|v)\geq 0$ $\implies$ $t(Sv|u)\geq 0$ we take $t$ equal $1$ and $-1$ we deduce that $(Sv|u)=0$
so  $u\in Im(S)^\perp$.

Comment: There is a general fact that ${\rm Im}S^\perp=\ker S$ for any self-adjoint operator, positive in particular. We have $\langle tSv,u-tv\rangle =-t^2\langle Sv,v\rangle \le 0.$ The latter is possible only if $v\in \ker S$ or $t=0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc actualy this exercise is about to prove ${\rm Im}S^\perp=\ker S$

Comment: I would prove the formula ${\rm Im}S^\perp=\ker S^*$ for any bounded operator $S,$ as follows. Let $u\in \ker S^*.$ Then for any $v\in {\rm Im}S$ we have $v=Sw$ for some $w$ and  $\langle v, u\rangle =\langle Sw,u\rangle =\langle w,S^*u\rangle =0.$ Hence $u\in {\rm Im}S^\perp. $ Conversely, let $u\in {\rm Im}S^\perp. $ Then $0=\langle Sw, u\rangle =\langle w, S^*u\rangle$ for any $w.$ Hence $S^*u=0,$ i.e. $u\in \ker S^*.$ When $S$ is nonnegative, then $S$ is self-adjoint which menas $S^*=S.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I do admit I'm not sure about the following (indeed, I've had trouble understanding your notation). Now, my attempt:

1. I understand both symbols (a|b) and (a,b) as the inner product of vectors a and b. I'll use only (a,b) for the inner product.
2. Actually, I've obtained $(tSv,u-tv)\leq 0, \forall t\in \mathbb{R}$. My proof:
   $$(tSv,u-tv)=(-Su+S(tv),u-tv)=-(S(u-tv),u-tv)\leq 0$$
3. To conclude, we apply linearity to the formula of point 2.:
   $$0\geq(tSv,u-tv)=t(Sv,u)-t^2(Sv,v)\Rightarrow 0\geq t(Sv,u)\Rightarrow (Sv,u)=0.$$ (This proof is quite similar to yours).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @Aliosha